# Dismiss Keyboard with UIScrollView

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, swift3

Before adding an UIScrollView, my `touchesBegan` would dismiss a keyboard. Since adding the scroll view, nothing dismisses. I've added `@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!` then inside `touchesBegan()`: `self.scrollView.endEditing(true)`, same issue.

How to dismiss the keyboard with the scroll view above the main view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `scrollview` is intercepting the touch event. Instead, add a `UITapGesture`to your main view (`self.view`) to dismiss the keyboard. Just make sure you assign `cancelsTouchesInView=false` to the tap gesture.

Comment: Thank you for that. I've add my answer to make it clearer to the public.

Comment: awesome, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Added to @rmp's answer, I want to make it clear what is meant to do:

```
// Add an outlet for the scroll view
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
```

Adding the `UITapGesture` in `viewDidLoad`:

**viewDidLoad():**

```
let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.touch))
recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
recognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

// Implementing the touch(), outside of viewDidLoad:

func touch() {
    //print("Touches")
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing this on `ScrollView` `didScroll` method?

And also you can do `self.view.endEditing(true)`

Comment: Im currently doing some reading as `touchesBegan()` is not being called when the scrollview is touched.